# Having problems in changing Google Maps location

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a liitle problem when i try to change location. I`m connected to map

```
var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 7,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.379433, 31.165579999999977),
   mapTypeControl: false,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

And now I need to change location on the map

```
<select onChange="changeCity()" id="city"><option value="50.4501, 30.523400000000038">Київ</option><option value="49.839683, 24.029717000000005">Львів</option></select>
```

For that I`m using:

```
function changeCity() {
   var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
   var city_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(city);
   map.setCenter(city_1);
}
```

But nothing happens (i see grey area). Please help...!

Comment: Check the browser's console, what JavaScript errors you see?

Comment: [14:37:06.243] Image corrupt or truncated: https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@199000000&src=apiv3&hl=uk&x=71&y=43&z=7&s=&style=api%7Csmartmaps @ https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@199000000&src=apiv3&hl=uk&x=71&y=43&z=7&s=&style=api%7Csmartmaps
[14:37:06.258] Image corrupt or truncated: https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@199000000&src=apiv3&hl=uk&x=71&y=44&z=7&s=G&style=api%7Csmartmaps @ https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@199000000&src=apiv3&hl=uk&x=71&y=44&z=7&s=G&style=api%7Csmartmaps

Comment: when i try: alert(city_1); rezult is Nan, Nan

Comment: Interesting, I would expect better error handling on Google's part (e.g. throwing error like "invalid Latitude") but oh well. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
somefunction("xx.xxxxxxx, xx.xxxxxxx");
```

is not equivalent to

```
somefunction(xx.xxxxxxx, xx.xxxxxxx);
```

Your values in the `option` tags are specified as **single *string*** instances, like `"50.4501, 30.523400000000038"` for Kiev. Notice the double quotes.

The `new LatLng()` constructor would expect **two *numeric* values**. So you have to parse the value string into separate latitude and longitude values and pass them to the `new LatLng()` constructor:

```
function changeCity() {

    var cityString = document.getElementById('city').value;
    //value string is split into two parts by the ',' character
    var arrayOfValues = cityString.split(','); 
    //parse latitude string part to a floating point value (first part)
    var lat = parseFloat(arrayOfValues[0]);
    //parse longitude string part to a floating point value (second part)
    var lon = parseFloat(arrayOfValues[1]);
    //create new LatLng instance with correct values
    var city_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    map.setCenter(city_1);
}
```

Reference:

- [Google Maps API docs: LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

Comment: And how is it relevant to this question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you see it now? If yes, please reconsider your downvote!

Comment: Actually seeing the OP's comment on the question looks like you don't need the parsing to numeric value, `new google.maps.LatLng(arrayOfValues[0], arrayOfValues[1])` will probably work just the same but parsing it might be good to perform some custom validation, just in case some values are invalid.

Comment: @ShadowWizard After looking up the [API doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), I don't know... It refers both parameters as numerics, but I can't tell, if it doesn't try some heuristics to convert to numeric if it it is given strings...

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the "Image corrupt or truncated" error will appear if each number is passed as a string (so parseFloat is needed for DOM extracted strings).